# Calling command from Perl, need to see output

Tags: perl, shellexecute

I need to call some shell commands from perl. Those commands take quite some time to finish so I'd like to see their output while waiting for completion.

The **system** function does not give me any output until it is completed.

The **exec** function gives output; however, it exits the perl script from that point, which is not what I wanted.

I am on Windows. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Backticks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlop#Backticks), or the `qx` command, run a command in a separate process and returns the output:

```
print `$command`;
print qx($command);
```

If you wish to see intermediate output, use [`open`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#open) to create a handle to the command's output stream and read from it.

```
open my $cmd_fh, "$command |";   # <---  | at end means to make command 
                                 #         output available to the handle
while (<$cmd_fh>) {
    print "A line of output from the command is: $_";
}
close $cmd_fh;
```

Comment: @Nathan - Probably, but it's even more important for the external command to have good buffering behavior -- either not buffering its output, or producing output quickly enough that buffering doesn't matter.

Comment: ++ for backticks AND piped open - The only nitpick I have is the lack of mention of the 3+ args version of the technique, which should be somewhat safer: open my $cmd_fh, '-|', $command;
Also, link: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens

Comment: This solution (also documented here: https://www.shlomifish.org/lecture/Perl/Newbies/lecture4/processes/opens.html) didn't seem to work for me calling another script --> Not sure if the script I'm calling isn't printing to the right output stream? (Thought it just looks like command line when I run it directly)

Comment: @fobbymaster If it is a long-running script, you may be [suffering from buffering](https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)